# ParseUser SignUpInBackground issue: Value == Null

Tags: android, parse-platform, parseexception

I've been trying to use the Parse library to access MongoDB in order to create users or objects for my Android application. The issue is that every time I attempt to SignUpInBackground or SignInInBackground I get this super unspecific error.

"java.lang.NullPointerException: value == null"

Just value == null.. I have no idea which value this refers to but the most frustrating part is that the code I'm using works perfectly in one app and despite copying it over, it always returns this error.

I usually wouldn't bother making a question for my issue but I've been trying to find a solution to this for about a week now and have been unable to find anything related to my issue online.

Hope someone out there has seen this before, as I'm about out of ideas for this one. Thanks in advance to anyone who gets back to me on this :)

The Sign Up Method:

```
  private void signUp(){
    String username = "Andy"; //Temp
    ParseUser user = new ParseUser();

    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setEmail(txtUsername.getText().toString());
    user.setPassword(txtPassword.getText().toString());

    Log.i(TAG,"SignUp method. Parse user = " + user.getUsername() + ", " + user.getEmail());

    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){
                Log.i(TAG, "Successfully created new user!");
                signIn();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new user. Error: " + e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Sign up failed! " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Error:

I/LogIn: Validation success
I/LogIn: SignUp method. Parse user = Andy, test
I/LogIn: Failed to create new user. Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: value == null

Edit:

While stepping through the parse libraries, I ended up with this error message several times in the log.

I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

Comment: Upload your complete error log.

Comment: Added it to the bottom, but all it really reports is value == null. :-/

Comment: Check all the parameters you are setting to the object.

Comment: I have, several times, even printed it out in the log. I've also stepped through the application to try and identify this "value" but still have no idea.

Comment: I've noticed this: user.setEmail(txtUsername.getText().toString()); Are you sure you're not reading username field by mistake and that is empty, since you've setting Andy manually.

Comment: That was a temporary measure to prove that it wasn't empty, the Log entry which returns the values of the ParseUser object always showed that all required fields were completed.  I've also stepped through it with the debugger and seen that both username and password are passed into the Parse library, however instead of giving me the error the app just closes while stepping through the code. 

I've since discovered that if you set their e-mail address as a username then you do not need to fill out the e-mail field at all, however regardless of any of my changes, I still receive the error.